# EJB never being called, not executing

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I've asked a similar question to this here: [Best way to interact with EJBs in Java EE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453317/best-way-to-interact-with-ejbs-in-java-ee) And the response was great, but I'm still not getting the results I'm looking for.  The EJB is still not being called even though I added the @PostConstruct annotation and converted the main class to a managed bean so that I could use injection. I think I'm close but I'm still not grasping some fundamental concepts involved with Java EE and EJBs. I think I might have to use some kind of timer event to make this work.

Again, my problem is that I want this class to execute at least once while it's running. It's getting twitter feed results from the URL, parsing the content into an array and then adding the first value to the database. The database management is done through another EJB so I have to use some kind of injection to access this class. Originally I had created a main method to test the code but I was getting Null reference exceptions because I was trying to inject and call an EJB's method from a regular java class.

Here is my new code with managed beans and PostConstruct annotation:

```
@ManagedBean

public class Driver {

@EJB RSSbean rssbean;   

@PostConstruct
public void initURL() throws IOException, JSONException{

    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "proxya..com");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
  /////////////auth code///////////////auth code/////////////////
        String username = System.getProperty("proxy.authentication.username");
        String password = System.getProperty("proxy.authentication.password");
        if (username == null) 
        {
            Authenticator.setDefault(new ProxyAuthenticator("s", "w"));
        }
  ///////////////end auth code/////////////////////////////////end

    URL twitterSource = new URL("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=news");
    ByteArrayOutputStream urlOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                IOUtils.copy(twitterSource.openStream(), urlOutputStream);
                String urlContents = urlOutputStream.toString();
                JSONObject thisobject = new JSONObject(urlContents);
                JSONArray names = thisobject.names();
                JSONArray asArray = thisobject.toJSONArray(names);
                JSONArray resultsArray = thisobject.getJSONArray("results");

                JSONObject(urlContents.trim());   

           JSONObject jsonObject = resultsArray.getJSONObject(0);   

            String twitterText = jsonObject.getString("text");

            System.out.println("Calling rssbean from Driver");
            **rssbean.updateDatabase("twitterText");**
                }}
```

The bottom line with the rssbean.updateDatabase is what needs to be executed for the updates to get persisted to the database.

Comment: I'm not sure `@Startup` works in conjunction with `@ManagedBean`.

Comment: I'll remove it from the question so as not to distract people. I've tried it with and without that specific annotation and it didn't affect the outcome.

Comment: Do you retrieve the bean somehow? If not that might be the problem. `@Startup` would cause the bean to be initialized at start time (automatically) but seems to only work for `@Singleton` beans.

Comment: Nothing is calling this Driver class to actually make it execute. I think tying it to some user event might be the only way. I kind of hoped that it would "just" run in the background on startup, somehow.

Comment: As I said, you'd need to use `@Startup` then, which only works in conjunction with `@Singleton`.

Comment: No change. I think Glassfish is ignoring these EJBs until they're needed. All I'm asking Glassfish to run is a index.xhtml page that is only connected to related EJB's through servlets. I was hoping the whole project would get deployed at once and the container would know that I want this specific class run at startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add `@Stateless` or `@Stateful` (Depending on your use/need) then remove the `@ManagedBean`. If you make it @Stateful be sure to implement Serializeable interface too.

Comment: I made this change but I think the problem is that nothing is really calling this Driver class. It's not tied to a user event so nothing is asking it to execute. I thought that maybe the @postconstruct would somehow make this run in the background but I think what I really need is a timer class of some kind or tie this to the first page load with a servlet somehow.

Comment: The @PostConstruct is just a method that will be called when after the object has been created (and gotten all it dependency resources injected). It is just a callback. I think you got the purpose of it wrong:=)

Comment: Probably :/   I think I'm also expecting it to run whenever I run the project on the server even if I'm just running the index.xhtml page. I think Glassfish might be ignoring these EJB's until they're needed. Because it's definitely being ignored.

Comment: If you don't invoke an EJB, neither would they be runned. It is just the same as "normal" Java. If you don't create an instance and invoke methods on "normal" Java class, what do you expect? They certainly won't be runned by them self even though they are in your project:)

Comment: That makes sense. But how would you suggest invoking an EJB that is parsing twitter data constantly and adding it to a database. There really is no one event or user that would invoke this it just needs to run if the application is running.

Comment: I am learning Java EE myself so I do not know if this is any good solution, but you could try the timer API?